# How to override angular 8 material styles colors using a variable?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular8

I need to change background color for this css code

```
.mat-toolbar.mat-primary {
```

> background

: #d12626;
        color: #fff;
    }

```
.mat-toolbar.mat-primary {
    background: #d12626;
    color: #fff;
}
```

I need to change the `background` for the above code. How to do that 
I tried

```
 [ngStyle]='    .mat-toolbar.mat-primary {
        background: #d12626;
        color: #fff;
    }
'
```

But not working 
Then i got another suggestion from stackoverflow

```
[style.font-size]="fontSize+'px'" this code is working for 'font-size' but not woking for my need code this is my need  [style.mat-toolbar.mat-primary.background]='#d12626'; but not working
```

I used this

```
.mat-toolbar.mat-primary {
        background: #d12626;
        color: #fff;
    }
```

code inside CSS code and it is working but I need to change the color dynamically.

I also need to update his colors 
 primaryColor  
 primaryLightColor  
 primaryDarkColor  
 secondaryColor  
 secondaryLightColor  
 secondaryDarkColor  
 primaryTextColor  
 secondaryTextColor

Answer (score 1):

dont set the material color as primary or secondary then you can use ngStyle like this

```html
<mat-toolbar [ngStyle]="{background:bgColor , color:'#fff'}">
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <span>Main Toolbar</span>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

> bgColor is just a component property, when you don't set the color property the component don't have any class so it 's easy to change the style

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6vrwxg)

Comment: I need to update primaryTextColor also. How to do that?

Comment: <color name="primaryColor">#ef9a9a</color>
<color name="primaryLightColor">#ffcccb</color>
<color name="primaryDarkColor">#ba6b6c</color>
<color name="secondaryColor">#ab47bc</color>
<color name="secondaryLightColor">#df78ef</color>
<color name="secondaryDarkColor">#790e8b</color>
<color name="primaryTextColor">#000000</color>
<color name="secondaryTextColor">#ffffff</color>

Comment: the same wht we did for the backgroud we can do it for the color

Comment: are you try to change the material colors and you want this to reflect to theme it self for all component in the hole project ? like you give the user the option to change the theme base color ? 

Comment: Yes, i need to allow user to change color for my app

Comment: i need to show a preview in admin panel to make user easy to identify the right color for  them and the preview is showing in angualr metrial ui

Comment: I got you point let me see if I have a way for this because your current answer will not work for you

Comment: I am allowing user to upload xml from from this website to my admin panel and it will distrbute to the app https://material.io/resources/color/#!/?view.left=0&view.right=0&primary.color=EF9A9A&secondary.color=AB47BC

Answer (score 0):

**Dynamic styles**

> You should make the CSS properties as camelcase, for the `font-size` should be like this `[style.fontSize.px]`. You check other solutions from [how-to-apply-dynamic-styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48223143/angular-4-how-to-apply-dynamic-styles#48223518).

**Override styles**

> We can do so using by combining the `:host` with the `::ng-deep` selector and most probably using for overriding [Material](https://material.angular.io/) styles:

```
:host ::ng-deep h2 {
    color: red;
}
```

**Custom theme for Angular Material**

> You can change a set of colors that will be applied to the Angular Material components.
>   https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Comment: I need to update this css code background  .mat-toolbar.mat-primary {
    background: #d12626;
    color: #fff;
}  so you mean to make change like this [style.matToolbar.matPrimary.background="my varible"? is that correct?

Comment: Are you mean overriding the material styles?

Comment: Great, it's simple to do with `::ng-deep`, I will edit the answer for more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Without hack, it's not possible to change on the fly the colors of you angular application because the way to style your application using Angular Material is to use theming (that is described here https://material.angular.io/guide/theming) and your theming scss files will be compiled to css at build time.

I think the only hack to change colors of your app on the fly is to identify the hex color that you want to change (for primary, secondary, etc...) and you rewrite your style tag in your document using serch / replace.

But keep in mind that Angular Material is not designed to let user change theme and colors because they provide palette and hue that have been designed to provide good contrast and best practice regarding UX. That's why the solution I give you is really a hack.

Answer (score 0):

the matrial dynamic color will be possible if the main set by css variable instaid of static hex values ,someone already publish a [library](https://github.com/johannesjo/angular-material-css-vars) to solve this by overwrite the main color to be used by css variables.

1️⃣ install *angular-material-css-vars* library 
`npm i angular-material-css-vars -S`

2️⃣ import `MaterialCssVarsModule` on app module

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    MaterialCssVarsModule.forRoot(),
  ],
   ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

3️⃣ use this service  `MaterialCssVarsService` to change angular material main color like primary ,secondary, warm...

```js
export class component {
  constructor(public materialCssVarsService: MaterialCssVarsService) {
    const hex = "#3f51b5"; // set default color color
    this.materialCssVarsService.setPrimaryColor(hex);
  }

  setPrimaryColor(color: string) {
    this.materialCssVarsService.setPrimaryColor(color);
  }
}
```

> you need to **remove** any existing @import '~@angular/material/theming'; from your main stylesheet file.

[**demo ‍♂️**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-dynamic-colors)

you may check this [question create angular material theme with css variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54595709/create-angular-material-theme-with-css-variables)  for more help

Comment: I think this is the right answer. I will check as soon as possible